# What can't you just use an arrow function inside of what React renders?

Tags: reactjs

Here's my use case. I have a component that needs access to a single variable in multiple places, like so:

```
    return (
      ...
          <div>
            {() => {
              const thisView = "day";
              return (
                <Button
                  isActive={calendarView === thisView}
                  onClick={() => {
                    setCalendarView(thisView);
                  }}
                >
                  Daily
                </Button>
              );
            }}
          </div>
      ...
    )
```

The above doesn't work as you get an error: `Type '() => React.JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.`

So, how does this work when I wrap it in a call to `.map`?...

```
    return (
      ...
          <div>
            {[null].map(() => {
              const thisView = "day";
              return (
                <Button
                  isActive={calendarView === thisView}
                  onClick={() => {
                    setCalendarView(thisView);
                  }}
                >
                  Daily
                </Button>
              );
            })}
          </div>
      ...
    )
```

But when I just want to pass an arrow function right where I might place a `.map()` of elements, all of a sudden I can't use an arrow function?

All I want to do is place a variable right there. I don't want to have to put it outside of the render function.

Comment: You aren’t invoking the function

Comment: @DanielA.White Oh, my gosh, no way! You mean this works with an IIFE?

Comment: It should but you don’t need it

Comment: @DanielA.White How would you do it? More than happy to give you the answer if you can provide me with an example. :) The IIFE works!!!

Answer (score 0):

As @DanielA.White pointed out in the comments, the anonymous function has to be invoked.

You can use an IIFE to invoke the anonymous function like so...

```
    return (
      ...
          <div>
            {(() => {
              const thisView = "day";
              return (
                <Button
                  isActive={calendarView === thisView}
                  onClick={() => {
                    setCalendarView(thisView);
                  }}
                >
                  Daily
                </Button>
              );
            })()}
          </div>
      ...
    )
```